# Алфавитный указатель списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть задача в сортировке списка по алфавиту и разбитии их по буквам. Т.е все ссылки на букву А должны быть в отдельном блоке, и т.д. в общем нужно сделать алфавитный указатель. Сейчас я уже отсортировал их по алфавиту, но застрял в том чтобы выбирать все начинающиеся с одинаковой буквы.
Все делаю на js.  Может кто-то знает каким способ это можно реализовать?

Comment: Предположу, что ты можешь циклом пробежать по списку, упорядоченному по алфавиту. Будет некая доп. переменная, а-ля буфер. С дефолтным значением 'А'.  В цикле смотреть первую букву слова. Если у текущего слова буква не такая как в буфере, значит это уже слова начинаются на другую букву. Заносишь эту букву в буфер. и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую так сделать, но мне этот способ кажется слишком неудобным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не самый логичный и удобный способ, но вот как я решил задачу(нужно было сделать срочно)

```
j(document).ready(function($){
var $elements = $('.loadPdf a');
var $target = $('.sortedpdf');
$elements.sort(function (a, b) {
    var an = $(a).text(),
        bn = $(b).text();
    if (an && bn) {
        return an.toUpperCase().localeCompare(bn.toUpperCase());
    }
    return 0;
});
$elements.detach().appendTo($target);

$('.sortedpdf a').html(function (i, html)
{
    return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="first">$1</span>');
});

    $('.sortedpdf a').each(function(){
        var firstLetter = $(this).find('.first').text();
        $(this).addClass(firstLetter);
    });

var classes = {};
$(".sortedpdf > a").each(function() {
    classes[$(this).attr("class")] = true;
});
for (singleClass in classes) {
    $("." + singleClass).wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
}
$(".column > a").each(function() {
    var alphabetIndex = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).parents('.column').before('<h3>'+alphabetIndex+'</h3>');
});
var seen = {};
$('.sortedpdf > h3').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

});